# Unity Player falling very slowly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created controls for a 3D Platformer game. Somehow the player is falling down very very slowly.

My player object got 2 components, the default capsule collider and the default Rigidbody. I didnt change anything there.

So my code is this one here:

```
float movementSpeed = 8;
float currentMovementSpeed;
float speedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
float turnSmoothTime = 0.2f;
float jumpPower = 5;
float airControlPercentage = 0.2f;
float turnSmoothVelocity;
float speedSmoothVelocity;
bool isGrounded;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = GroundCheck(); // Is player grounded?

        Vector2 inputDirection = (new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"))).normalized;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded) // Jump handling
            Debug.Log("Player Jump");

        if (inputDirection != Vector2.zero)
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, Mathf.Atan2(inputDirection.x, inputDirection.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime)); // Rotate

        currentMovementSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentMovementSpeed, movementSpeed * inputDirection.magnitude, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

        playerRigid.velocity = transform.forward * currentMovementSpeed + Vector3.up * playerRigid.velocity.y * Time.deltaTime; // Move

        currentMovementSpeed = (new Vector2(playerRigid.velocity.x, playerRigid.velocity.z)).magnitude;
    }

    private float GetModifiedSmoothTime(float smoothTime) // Limit the control while in air
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            return smoothTime;

        if (airControlPercentage == 0)
            return float.MaxValue;

        return smoothTime / airControlPercentage;
    }

    private bool GroundCheck() // Player is grounded?
    {
        if (true)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Does someone knows what to do here?

Comment: Did you try changing the mass in the `Rigidbody` component ?

Comment: Also look at the _drag_ value of your `Rigidbody`: if too high this may cause a slow in movements.

Answer (score 2):

It probably has something to do with your current gravity. Check in `edit -> project settings -> physics` the value of your gravity. In my case is `-9,81`. Change it to a higher value and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. How to fix it:

In this line of code

```
playerRigid.velocity = transform.forward * currentMovementSpeed + Vector3.up * playerRigid.velocity.y * Time.deltaTime;
```

Take out

```
* Time.deltaTime
```

Now the player is falling correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually , `transform.forward` effect the `y` component of the body thus effects the gravity acting on the body.

Use

`rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontal , -1 , vertical) * speed` ; .

It will work, or simply use `AddForce` to drive the player.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use gravity calculations, changing the rigidbody in your code can do this.

```
 //rb.velocity = moveInput * moveSpeed;
```

for example will screw with your movement, even when a button isn't being pressed.

using something like:

```
   if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.001f)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

will simply add forces on top of the calculations, instead of changing them prior to

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the slow descending of my game character was solved by eliminating unnecessary calls to the physics system in the FixedUpdate() function. For example, when a joystick's X-axis and/or Y-axis are in the zero position.

I call addForce, velocity, rb transforms, etc. only if the absolute joystick value (- and +) exceeds a minimum value, in my case 0.04. Without these tests, these physics calls are done every time FixedUpdate() is called. This seems to overload the physics system, because at the same time, physics is also processing gravity etc.
Note that merely setting the joystick's dead zones in the Unity Input System doesn't solve this problem.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(stick.x) > 0.04) // prevent unnecessary physics call.
    {
        rb.transform.eulerAngles = rb.transform.eulerAngles - new Vector3(0, stick.x * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed * -1, 0);
    }
    if (Mathf.Abs(stick.y) > 0.04) // prevent unnecessary physics call.
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * stick.y * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```